# How to implement Android Background service in a NativeScript Angular project?

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, background-service, angular-nativescript

I'm trying to create a background service for `nativescript-geolocation` to get notifications when an event has been triggered.

I've found a lot of examples for the general NS version, but **nothing for the Angular** version and I can't find the way to implement it.

Currently, I'm getting `Class "com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService" not found.` error messages.

Services have been declared in the AndroidManifest.xml, deleted the platforms dir, and did a clean build.

```
<service android:name="com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService"
         android:exported="false" >
</service>
<service android:name="com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService26"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
         android:enabled="true"
         android:exported="false">
</service>
```

I use this as a reference and **trying to create the Angular version** of this
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/tree/master/demo

**background-service.ts**

```
import * as geolocation from "nativescript-geolocation";
import { Accuracy } from "tns-core-modules/ui/enums";
import * as application from "tns-core-modules/application";
import { device } from "tns-core-modules/platform";
import * as Toast from "nativescript-toast";

let watchId;

function _clearWatch() {
  if (watchId) {
    geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
    watchId = null;
  }
}

function _startWatch() {
  geolocation.enableLocationRequest().then(function () {
    _clearWatch();
    watchId = geolocation.watchLocation(
      function (loc) {
        if (loc) {
          let toast = Toast.makeText('Background Location: \n' + loc.latitude + ', ' + loc.longitude);
          toast.show();
          console.log('Background Location: ' + loc.latitude + ' ' + loc.longitude);
        }
      },
      function (e) {
        console.log("Background watchLocation error: " + (e.message || e));
      },
      {
        desiredAccuracy: Accuracy.high,
        updateDistance: 1.0,
        updateTime: 3000,
        minimumUpdateTime: 100
      });
  }, function (e) {
    console.log("Background enableLocationRequest error: " + (e.message || e));
  });
}
application.on(application.exitEvent, _clearWatch);

export function getBackgroundServiceClass() {
  if (application.android) {
    if (device.sdkVersion < "26") {
      @JavaProxy("com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService")
      class BackgroundService extends (<any>android).app.Service {
        constructor() {
          super();
          return global.__native(this);
        }
        onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId) {
          console.log('service onStartCommand');
          this.super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
          return android.app.Service.START_STICKY;
        }
        onCreate() {
          console.log('service onCreate');
          _startWatch();
        }
        onBind(intent) {
          console.log('service onBind');
        }
        onUnbind(intent) {
          console.log('service onUnbind');
        }
        onDestroy() {
          console.log('service onDestroy');
          _clearWatch();
        }
      }
      return BackgroundService;
    } else {
      @JavaProxy("com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService26")
      class BackgroundService26 extends (<any>android.app).job.JobService {
        constructor() {
          super();
          return global.__native(this);
        }
        onStartJob(): boolean {
          console.log('service onStartJob');
          _startWatch();
          return true;
        }
        onStopJob(jobParameters: any): boolean {
          console.log('service onStopJob');
          this.jobFinished(jobParameters, false);
          _clearWatch();
          return false;
        }
      }
      return BackgroundService26;
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
export const BackgroundServiceClass = getBackgroundServiceClass();
```

**app.component.tns.ts**

```
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

import { BackgroundServiceClass } from "@src/background-service";


import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
const utils = require("tns-core-modules/utils/utils");
import * as application from "tns-core-modules/application";
import { device } from "tns-core-modules/platform";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})

export class AppComponent {




  /* Background servie stuffs */
  page: Page;
  watchIds = [];
  jobId = 308; // the id should be unique for each background job. We only use one, so we set the id to be the same each time.
  com: any;

  constructor(

  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){


    application.on(application.exitEvent, this._stopBackgroundJob);


  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){

  }

  _stopBackgroundJob() {
    if (application.android) {
      let context = utils.ad.getApplicationContext();
      const jobScheduler = context.getSystemService((<any>android.content.Context).JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
      if (jobScheduler.getPendingJob(this.jobId) !== null) {
        jobScheduler.cancel(this.jobId);
        console.log(`Job Canceled: ${this.jobId}`);
      }
    }
  }

    startBackgroundTap() {
      if (application.android) {
        let context = utils.ad.getApplicationContext();
        if (device.sdkVersion >= "26") {
          const jobScheduler = context.getSystemService((<any>android.content.Context).JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
          const component = new android.content.ComponentName(context, BackgroundServiceClass.class);
          const builder = new (<any>android.app).job.JobInfo.Builder(this.jobId, component);
          builder.setOverrideDeadline(0);
          jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
        } else {
          let intent = new android.content.Intent(context, BackgroundServiceClass.class);
          context.startService(intent);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="__PACKAGE__" android:versionCode="13" android:versionName="1.31">
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

  <application android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
      <service android:name="com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService"
               android:exported="false" >
      </service>

      <service android:name="com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService26"
               android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
               android:enabled="true"
               android:exported="false">
      </service>
      <activity android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode" android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">
            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you find any info on the issue? maybe Manoj can help but he hasn't seen the thread here?

Comment: I don't know what happened with him, I've also posted this 4 times directly to the NS dev community channel, but no one cares... since they announced https://nstudio.io/ they don't really answer my questions

Comment: Ah, that's a shame, I did come here from the link from ns dev slack. I wish I could help you or had any knowledge of this one.

Comment: I'm really hopeful Progress will support NS better in the future, it's an awesome thing to have in the world, we love this so far and want to invest in it

Comment: Does the angular version of the demo [that is included in that repo](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/tree/master/demo-angular) not function correctly?

Comment: @IanMacDonald, unfortunately, the background service is not included in the angular demo.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem you mention try this:

1. Check your version of Nativescript and the version the example. Breaking changes between versions may be affecting. Try a downgrade to Nativescript 5, create a new project and paste your code.
2. Then, try a clean build.

For Background Location Tracking, I suggest you to try Foreground Services combined with nativescript-geolocation plugin. Check this article is a well explained tutorial of the first topic:

https://dev.to/ozymandiasthegreat/android-continuous-background-services-with-nativescript-42c9

Repo link:

https://github.com/OzymandiasTheGreat/Nativescript-ServiceExample/blob/master/package-lock.json